# RF ISM 433MHz Module Using Rpi RadioHead Low Speed Problem

Tags: pi-3b+, arduino, nrf24l01

I have a rf module 433Mhz  which consist of a transmitter and a receiver, I used virtualwire and Radiohead library in Arduino and it's pretty fast. When I shifted that to rpi there were no dedicated library and I used piVirtualWire and rc switch(python) and it is pretty slow. How can I run that Arduino code on rpi or suggest me ways I can increase speed of the python library or how can I write that code in c++ or c# in rpi and achieve the speed.
Thanks

Comment: Could we have links to the software you are using and details of any modifications to that software you have made.  We also need details of what "it is pretty slow" means in time terms.

Comment: @Ambuje Gupta, Ah, let me see. VirtualWire is superceded by RadioHead.  Perhaps you can try RH's NRF24 driver for Rpi.  Or let us know the instructions you are following. Please confirm you are using Rpi4B python 3.7.3 and NRF24.  I have RF12B in hand.  I can try to reproduce your situation if your tutorial is for Rpi python and RF12B V1.1.

Comment: @tlfong01 The question is about 433 MHz.

Comment: @Ambuje Gupta, By the way, last time I played with ISM433 is SPI RF12B:
http://www.hoperf.de/upload/rf/RFM12B.pdf.  I am interested to use the more trendy NRF modules. So if you are in for NRF, I do have a couple of NRF modules in hand to try it, but all my experience is about RF12.

Comment: @joan - https://github.com/r10r/rcswitch-pi , yes it is sending 10 values in 4.5 second

Comment: @tlfong01 - it's about 433Mhz not about 2.4Ghz.

Comment: It's like when I run the code in Arduino it's pretty fast , because of it's libraries, and in RPI the libraries are slow is there a way I can run Arduino code in rpi?

Comment: @AmbujeGupta You need to edit new information into your question.  Not everyone will read comments.

Comment: @AmbujeGupta, Ah, I mixed up 433MHz RF12B with 2.4GHz nRF24L01.  My apologies.  My experience is only RF12B. I used C++ to directly SPI talk to RF12B, without any library, therefore pretty fast. If you wish to run fast, you can forget the RadioHead library (which I think slowing down things), and use Rpi4B Thonny 3.2 python 3.7.3 to write SPI interface to directly talk to the RF12B or similar RF modules. You can even "compile" your bottleneck slow python functions, to further speed up things.  BTW, you did not mention which RF module you are using, so I might have made a wrong guess. Sorry.